# How to get month-end dates with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, date

I have a table with daily prices of some assets (products) with some days missing. I want to get month-end prices in order to calculate price volatility for each year. Price volatility is defined as the standard deviation of month-end prices.

If a month-end date is missing, for example like 31. December 2010, the algorithm must search the dates of the product backwards and use the nearest date as month-end date.

Is there an easy way to implement this logic with c#?

Comment: What if there is no record for a month?

Comment: Have your tried anything as yet?

Comment: I guess I answered a different question. You'll need to specify how the data is stored (what's the table? Is it a database? What are its fields, etc...).

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL, or Entity Framework?

Comment: My answers to your comments: What if there is no record for a month? The algorithm should search backwards up to a predefined number of days (for example 60). The day can also be in the previous month as long as this day count parameter permits. Have your tried anything as yet? I tried to do something with R (matrices and vectors) but no clean solution so far. Now I need a solution with c#. Relevant fields of data table: product, date (day), price. I would prefer a solution with LINQ if possible, but the solution can be anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need is probably date sampling (or date algorithms) with target and source dates.

See 
Filtering and sampling tables by dates
http://finaquant.com/filtering-and-sampling-tables-by-dates/2606

Answer (score 1):

ok - if you want end of month...

```
DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now; // start with any date....
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(theDate.Year, theDate.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1);
```

then use that in your Linq.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too complex.

Assume you have a list of `PriceData` instances, with `PriceData` being:

```
class PriceData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

List<PriceData> prices = ...

var lastPricePerMonth = prices.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Year * 12 + y.Date.Month)
                              .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date)
                                            .First());
```

This will return the latest `PriceData` object for each month.